# Copying java console output into excel, rows rather than columns

Tags: java, excel, console, output

I'm sure this hasn't been asked before as this seems like a strange question perhaps.

I have a program which essentially prints out some important data to the console. I then want to simply copy this data and paste it into excel. When I copy and paste it, it appears on new rows on the document, I need this to be in new columns. For example instead of:

Data1

Data2

Data3

I need
Data1 | Data 2 | Data3

Currently I am printing these to the console using:
System.out.println("Data1");
However, I can use print instead of println, but I guess there must be some character which is required to seperate these. I tried \r but this didn't seem to work.

Strangely, I also cannot simply paste transposed. In order to get the "transposed" option in excel, I need to paste the cells, and then copy them to the clipboard again and paste. I suppose if there was a way to see what is on the clipboard when you copy a set of cells next to each other I would know what I need to output to have the same results.

I don't even need to use System.out.print, I am happy to copy these directly to the clipboard using java if this makes the solution easier.

The issue is that this task is going to be so many times, it makes sense to not have to copy/paste into excel, then copy it again and paste as transposed.

Thanks,

Comment: Use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to write an excel file directly.

Comment: Use CSV and then export to Excel manually

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The problem with this is that the excel file already exists and needs to really be done by hand. The excel document consists of a whole load of this output, then a few comments which need to be made by hand

Comment: I think I have it, my mistake was using \r instead of \t. I can't believe I didn't get this, I've been messing with it for hours trying to get it to work then as soon as I post it clicks. Hopefully this helps other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\r` should be a carriage return, so I suppose that's why it doesn't work with that. Have you tried `\t` for a tab?

Or `System.out.println("Data1,Data2,Data3")` to get comma-delimited, if you can be sure that there are no commas in your data?

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Seems to silly of me now. Thanks for your help! It says I need to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer, but this one is the perfect answer so I'll accept it as soon as I can. Thanks again.